# How to grant permission to files not owned by application

Tags: android, permission-denied

When trying to send files not created by my app to Firebase Storage, I get an exception with the message **"/path/to/the/file permission denied"**.

However, when I create in my code a file in the internal directory of my app (*/data/data/package_name/files/*) and send it to the Firebase storage it works.

***How to send other files located elsewhere in the internal storage without troubles ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add permission in the manifest and also check and ask for permission to access storage in the runtime.

In manifest, add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For runtime permissions, I hope this library will help you. 
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to get permission in the _internal storage_ ?

Comment: Internal storage means the storage owned by the app, external storage means everything except that incliding phone's internal storage. you don't need permission for internal storage but you need permission to access phone's storage.